# Erro mkConfigObj Knex

Tags: javascript, migrations, knex.js

Estou criando uma migration a partir do Knex, mas quando rodo o comando

```
npx knex migrate:latest --knexfile knexfile.ts migrate:latest
```

Recebo o seguinte erro:

> No configuration file found and no commandline connection parameters passed at mkConfigObj

Já acessei o arquivo que o erro aponta, são algumas configurações do CLI.

Meu knexfile.ts

```js
import path from 'path';

module.exports = {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
        filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'database.sqlite')
    },

    migrations:{
        directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'migrations')
    }
};
```

Comment: O arquivo knexfile.ts tem que estar na raiz do projeto. Provável que o seu não esteja.

Comment: Eu já tive esse problema, e era de fato o caminho errado do knexfile.ts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oie, tive o mesmo erro. era pq estava no diretório errado. Entre no diretório do back-end, e executa o comando dnv que da certo.

1. npm install knex
2. npm install sqlite3 (se for esse q vc estiver usando)
3. npx knex migrate:latest --knexfile knexfile.ts migrate:latest

Funcionou comigo.